# Photoshop exports image but not layer mask (no transparency)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, save, file-format

I have a photo of a person.

I used quick selection to select person and then a layer mask (which is linked) to get transparent background.

Looks fine in export window (background is checkerboard), but export png file is original photo with photo background, not transparent background.

Comment: Hi zpanama, welcome to GD.SE! Are you saying the PNG shows transparency in the save for web window (Transparency checkbox checked) but when you look at the exported PNG after the save, it shows a solid background? How are you viewing the exported PNG? Did you export with the background layer invisible? Are you sure you had the transparency checkbox checked in the save for web window?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you export the image to PNG-24, as PNG-8 only supports 256 indexed  colour palette, and since it's a photo, it will most likely use colours without any alpha (or very limited alpha - just too many to choose from).

Then if you want to use it in a web, I would compress it using tinypng.org (fully supports alpha transparency).

note: PNG-24 with transparency actually makes it PNG-32 but that's not something you need to be concerned about.

Also, as @AndrewH has said in his comment, make sure that you check the box for transparency.